# What do you call a game that is both simultaneous and sequential?

Tags: game-theory

Is there a standard term for a game that has both simultaneous and sequential parts? Is it a mixed game? A combined game?

Answer (score 1):

A sequential game with imperfect information?

Comment: Yes I forgot that's one name for it. For my needs though 5 words is a bit too verbose. It will be classification in a database. I was hoping maybe there is some 2-3 word term out there